# Forward declaration incomplete type, recursive

Tags: c++

I have two classes Observer and Subject and ObserverA, ObserverB which are extending Observer (for implementing Observer DP).

In Subject I have a vector of pointers to Observer class:

```
class Subject {
    std::vector<Observer*> obs;
    int state;
public:
    Subject(): state(0) {}

    void notifyAll() {
      for(std::vector<Observer*>::iterator it = obs.begin(); it != obs.end(); it++)
      {
         (*it)->update();
      }
    }
}

...
};
```

In Observer, I also have a Subject:

```
class Observer {
protected:
   Subject subj;   
public:
    virtual void update() {};
};
```

ObserverA, ObserverB alike:

```
class ObserverA: public Observer {
public:    
    ObserverA(Subject s) {
        subj = s;
        s.attach(this);
    }

    virtual void update() {
        std::cout << "Update A, state subj: " << subj.getState() << std::endl;    
    }
};
```

Before declaring class Subject, I added forward declaration for class Observer. However I am getting compiling errors:

```
Observer.h: In member function ‘void Subject::notifyAll()’:
Observer.h:27:17: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Observer’
            (*it)->update();
                 ^
Observer.h:7:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class Observer’
 class Observer;
   ^
```

I have a vector of pointers to Observer, in Subject class, I forward declared Obsever class and Observer class knows about Subect, why do I still have the error?

Comment: If you want to actually be able to *use* the functions of a class, you need the full definition of it. If you only have a forward declaration how would the compiler actually know what member functions it have?

Comment: IMO, it is different "a duplicated question" and two questions about the same issue. A programmer who know the solution will immediately know the answer is similar, but a new programmer will not, and probably that is why he is asking and not already reading the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the implementation of `Subject::notifyAll` into a .cpp file (in fact, do so for all member function implementations) - say the subject.cpp file. Then keep the forward declaration for `Observer` in the header file that contains the `Subject` class definition, and `#include "observer.hpp"` in the subject.cpp.

The forward declaration is sufficient in the header file since the class definition only ever refers to `Observer*`. On the other hand, the .cpp file needs to see the full `Observer` class definition, since it calls a member function on an `Observer` instance.

So :

```
// subject.hpp
#include <vector>

class Observer;

class Subject {
  std::vector<Observer*> obs;
  int state;
public:
  Subject(): state(0) {}

  void notifyAll();
};
```

and :

```
// subject.cpp
#include "subject.hpp"

#include "observer.hpp"

#include <vector>

void Subject::notifyAll() {
  for(std::vector<Observer*>::iterator it = obs.begin(); it != obs.end(); it++)
  {
    (*it)->update();
  }
}
```

Furthermore, your observer implementation can be improved quite a bit. Eg. :

- don't keep a `Subject` in the `Observer`. You will likely have multiple subjects for the same observer, but more importantly : the observer doesn't need to keep track of the subjects.
- don't link a `Subject` to an `Observer` in the `Observer` constructor. That would only allow you to have one subject per observer. Instead, attach an `Observer` to a `Subject` in the `Subject` constructor (or another member function).
- don't pass by value when you don't want to make a copy. Instead, pass by reference (eg. `const Subject&`).

Comment: Solved by moving Observer definition before Subject definition, and in Observer I used a pointer to Subject.

Comment: @georgiana_e : you should really consider splitting your code in different files - you'll make your life a lot easier.